# How can I run the unit tests for ngCordova?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ngcordova

I’ve contributed to [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com)​ and will create a pull request. How can I run the existing tests? If I can run those I’ll update the mocks & tests for my plugin changes too.

I’ve tried `gulp karma` and `gulp karma-watch` but these throw, `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`. This is from a cloned copy of ng-cordova, not integrated into a project.

Comment: You should raise a issue in the Ngcordova github repo.  I say that because I help maintain that project.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker done, thanks! https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/1122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from George Stocker:

`git clone https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova.git`

`cd ng-cordova`

`npm install`

`bower install`    *(This was the missing piece for me)*

`gulp karma`

Thanks George!